# Python PILLOW Can't compare two images correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-comparison

I want to compare two images and then decide whether they are the same or not but the PIL library is not able to tell me the correct result. Even I use both ways to compare them it returns true for two different grayscale images.

```
difference = ImageChops.difference(image1.convert('L'), image2.convert('L'))
if not difference.getbbox() and list(image1.convert('L').getdata()) == list(image2.convert('L').getdata()):
```

I am using it in this manner but I couldn't handle this problem.

These are the example images for that situation:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Please share the two images you compared and show the difference image.

Comment: I have added them.

Answer (score 4):

Your images have got a superfluous alpha channel. It appears to work if you discard that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageChops

im1 = Image.open('LQk4R.png').convert('L')
im2 = Image.open('gKx4l.png').convert('L')

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1,im2)
diff.show()
```

In `IPython`:

```
In [13]: diff.getbbox() 
Out[13]: (0, 0, 220, 63)

In [14]: im1.getdata() == im2.getdata()
False
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it works but sometimes still doesn't work. But I solved it by another way of doing this process.